# How to make positive reinforcement effective when the other parent does not adopt this approach?

Tags: discipline

My children are two years and nine months old. Their mother and I have separated and we share parenting time. She and I have very different parenting philosophies. I adhere to positive reinforcement and focus on natural consequences. Their mother thinks that the kids at this age cannot be negotiated with and that they only hear "lalala" unless you really raise your voice, and she frequently resorts to time-outs.

I recently find my approach to have become increasingly ineffective. As an example, I'd tell the kids "if you do activity A, you'd get [a reinforcer]" and they pretty much just ignore me. I know they are ignoring me because I'm the "nice" parent and they know that I'm not going to be loud. Similarly, if I change my intonation and say "No, you're hurting the chair," they now ignore me too, presumably because my changing intonation is no match for the voice raising of their mother's. Their mother has expressed similar frustration – that the children are noncompliant when they are with her in spite of her disciplinary efforts. She says it's because I'm being too soft and sending an inconsistent message to the children.

I have no intention of giving up on my overall parenting philosophy. But given the context, how can I make my approach more effective?

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation - there will be an age when yelling means the kids hear “lalala”. Also know n as puberty.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks that's a good insight. I guess I generally disagree that they only hear "lalala" right now, since they are verbal and can clearly articulate their feelings.

Comment: No, Stephie means that they just tune you out, not that they don't understand the words. See also https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/22811/my-6-year-old-son-does-not-listen-when-i-tell-him-to-stop-something-immediately/22814#22814

Comment: "Hurting the chair" ? Not sure if it helps, but I always explained stuff to my kid logically (i.e. a chair can't be hurt, but it can be damaged) if only for my own sanity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know they are ignoring me because I'm the "nice" parent and they know that I'm not going to be loud.

How do you know that? Certainly they've not expressed such an opinion, so I'm *guessing* you are *guessing*. And on top of (purely) guessing, you're *blaming* your ex for what is natural in children.

> ...given the context, how can I make my approach more effective?

Get a new context that doesn't involve guesswork or blame.

Two year olds like to push boundaries and flex their little control muscles; like everyone else, they want and enjoy having agency (though I wouldn't expect them to express this concept.) That's why that age is called ["the terrible twos".](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/childdevelopment/positiveparenting/toddlers2.html)

Read about the stages kids go through, and know that kids **will** test boundaries, especially when the boundaries are not consistent. Read about positive parenting and be the best father you can be regardless of "the circumstances". Because that is really all you can do.

If you're seriously concerned about your ex's approach, maybe you can take parenting classes together, or try for more custody. You can hope, but you can't expect her to change her parenting style, because the only person you can truly control is yourself. (That includes your kids.) I suspect you'll feel more peace about the behavior of your children if you let go of that excuse, know what's common, and figure out what you (alone) can do better as a father and role model.

**Edited to add:** You state your kids have been acting out more at preschool, and your wife (also guessing) blamed you. This much is not guesswork: when there's a big shift in a young child's life, there will be a behavior change. Potty trained children often regress to diapers. Well behaved children will bite/act out. (My eldest did both when their sibling was born.) Young children can't process their emotions like adults do, and often they *react* in some new/uncharacteristic way. The preschool teacher has probably seen this before, and knows (or should) that this is normal in a divorce/new sibling/other. (My eldest's preschool teacher also informed me of the new biting and asked about the effect the baby was having on his behavior at home.) Don't take it personally. It's *normal*, and it will get better.

Comment: "because the only person you can control is yourself". I'm in a similar situation and this is definitely what I needed to hear. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My ex said to the kids' teacher that my being soft is causing their defiance several times recently. My frustration leaked through and I apologize; it wasn’t my intention to be accusatory. TBH I thought these were normal behaviors for this stage, but their teacher seems to indicate their behaviors are out of norm, making me concerned. I consulted with a friend specializing in childcare and received good advice. As you said, we shouldn’t worry about controlling what we cannot; we should focus on being the best versions of ourselves first and guide the kids accordingly.

Comment: @Colin FWIW, I don't think you need to worry about being too soft, as long as you're firm on things that actually matter. I'm similar to you and very laissez-faire, not because I want to be passive, but because I want to give my boys the freedom to make choices themselves. It's true that they push back hard on me, but my eldest is also a very early independent thinker because of it. In my view, the end goal is maintaining a positive relationship with your kids over time, so when they're older and it's more critical, they're still receptive.

Comment: With that said, my wife has always been firmer with them, and we're now at a juncture where our eldest fights less with her, because he's a little afraid of her.

Comment: @Colin - Please see my edit. No need to apologize!!! Teachers will report behaviors that are out of the norm *for that child*. I'm pretty sure (just guessing, though) that the teacher knows better than to blindly believe what one side in a conflict reports. I'm sorry you're experiencing these difficulties. Separation/divorce is hard on everyone. Glad you came here to ask.

Comment: Thanks @mcraenich. I had the similar idea that I want my kids to be autonomous. Throughout my life, my parents told me that they trust me to do the right things, but they are there to offer advice when I’m in doubt. That has served me well and I want to take the same approach.

Comment: Thanks @anongoodnurse! One insight I’ve been given is that we should take care of our own emotions/feelings before we can best help the kids during difficult times. I think I’ve gotten better at not taking things personally, but it’s still a work in progress as you can tell. I’m not concerned about which side the teachers believe; I know the kids are with caring and capable teachers and that’s all that matters...

Comment: … My own focuses are on making sure our conflicts are not leaking through to the kids & on better understanding the best parenting approach in a split family. Thanks for the assurance that things do get better. My friend similarly mentioned these regressions as normal; she told me to stop making assumptions (aka stop guessing as you said) and to try to better understand the underlying reasons for the children's behaviors. I’ve also learned a lot reading old threads here and this is now part of my support system =).

Comment: @Colin - You might be interested in searching the tab for co-parenting as well. :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks! Started browsing already. I also picked up Kazdin's book and it's been a great read so far. Thanks again for your answer!